# How to disable styling on man pages?

Tags: terminal, colors, man

Is there an easy way to turn off all styling on man pages? Colors, bold, italics, everything... If not, what is an uneasy way?

Comment: Weird, all the answers work for Ubuntu, but not Gentoo...

Answer (score 4):

`man`'s output is formatted by [groff](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/1/groff), and more specifically the last step is post-processing by [grotty](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/1/grotty), which is responsible for turning the device-independent output of `groff` into something that can be displayed on a terminal.

So, the easiest option is to force `grotty` to use the simplest tty available, with no fancy formatting capabilities, that is the "dumb" terminal:

```
env TERM=dumb man ping
```

Comment: Like I said, I didn't spend long ;-). This is much better, but I would enhance it with `PAGER="less -d" TERM=dumb man ping`.

Answer (score 4):

At least with the default Ubuntu setup (this may vary between `man` implementations), `man` generates control characters only if its standard output is connected to a terminal (even with `TERM=dumb`). So pipe its output manually into your pager (or into a file).

```
man man | less
```

Answer (score 2):

Granted, I didn't spend long trying this, but the only way I found works, but also disables any type of pagination*.

```
export PAGER=cat
man man
```

Or,

```
PAGER=cat man man
```

Or create a bash function in your `.bash_profile`,

```
function boringman()
{
    PAGER=cat man $*
}
```

However, depending on your terminal settings this might not work for you.

If you wanted to get *really* fancy, you can combine `man2html`, `lynx` and `more` or `less`. Set `PAGER` to something like `man2html --some --options | lynx -stdin -dump | less --some --options`. I don't know enough about man2thml to describe correctly how to do it, so I'll leave that as an exercise for you. It's a little overkill, but you get pagination.

*The control characters are actually preserved, just not displayed. Piping this output through `more` or `less` proves the point.